# GWT JSON & MYSQL

Tags: mysql, json, gwt

I am trying to get records from a mysql server, then encode them to json using the jdbc driver for mysql without using rpc. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JSON instead of RPC. How to encode the data is up to you.

http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/JSON.html